# Dojo javascript files/paths are not instantly showing in browser using Sails.js

Tags: node.js, dojo, sails.js, intern

I have a lot of files in my `assets/js` directory. At first I thought I was somehow losing the ability to see/serve files from `sails`. But after I let `sails` run for a little while, it seems `sails` found my files in the `assets/js` directory and I was able to run my `intern` tests. I'm assuming there is some type of behind the scenes cache going on that must run before I can successfully make a request. Is this the reason, and if so, how can I disable it for a more instant access to my files?

Answer (score 0):

Sails.js needs to do several things before lifting the server, you can try `sails lift --verbose` to see what's happening.

Also, if you dont mind, take a look the `.js` files under `tasks/config/`, Sails.js uses them to link/copy/build assets before starting.